# Always reload page on redirect in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form that can be called up and submitted from any page of the site.  The trigger button, located in site's nav bar, will display the form in a modal-like UI and process the submit action via an AJAX call.  If the POST comes back successfully, it will contain a Location header with the URL of the page than needs to be shown next.

I need the browser to always reload the page when redirecting to this returned Location.  If I simply do `window.location = xdr.getResponseHeader('Location')` and the current URL minus the hash fragment is the same as the new URL minus the hash fragment, the page won't reload (at least that's the behavior in Chrome I'm seeing).

Short manual parsing of the returned URL and comparing against the current page URL to tell when to call `reload()` and when to simply reassign `window.location`, is there a more straight forward way to achieve the desired page reloading behavior?

Comment: What's wrong with parsing the URL? There are many implementations of this and no performance hit since it's simple. Otherwise, perhaps you should do a full pageform submit rather than ajax, then just do the redirect server-side.

Comment: I have no problems with parsing the URL as long as I am not missing a solution that doesn't require doing so.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I believe you should just do a traditional form submit rather than Ajax. Then handle the redirect server-side, where it should always force a pageload even if it's a postback.

Comment: I don't want to reload the page while the form's data has validation issues.  A traditional form submit flow would break this requirement.

Comment: A lot of stacks include client-side validation as well in order to handle this case but I understand if it's too big of a modification.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky Interesting thought and strategy to use the server as a backup validator, for an improved user experience. Sometimes I learn more from questions than answers.

Comment: @Wayne: My backend is Django, which has very well integrated and rich data validation services, so I don't even try to mirror them on the client side.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky Can I assume that when xdr is not a redirect it tells the user what part of the input is the problem. Back to making it work, if the location will always be the same the location.reload() method could be used when a redirect, or form validated, response comes back.

Comment: Just FYI my company uses a Java builder framework that has an RDD file -- the validation is done client side but then also when posted to the backend to avoid malicious submissions.

Comment: @Wayne, yes the AJAX request will get back either a 205 response that contains a newly rendered form with error messages or a 201 response with the redirect URL.  Since the form can be submitted from any page on the site, the redirect URL is not guaranteed to be the same as the current URL.